# How to pass arguments when redirecting to another view in Django 3 (Python)

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views

I want to pass variables to my views in django but I get errors... The code is simply attempting to pass text into a view while redirecting. Basically the user will fill out a form, and the content of that form will be displayed on another page. However, if I run the following code, I come across this error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'view2' with
> arguments '('hi',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view2$']

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            submit_form(request)
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})

def view2(request, text):
    return render(request, 'page2.html', {'my_text':text})

def submit_form(request):
    # Just using 'hi' for simplicity
    return redirect(view2, 'hi')
```

page2.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}

{{ my_text }}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('view2', views.view2, name='view2'),
]
```

I suspect the error is from me doing something wrong in the views.py, but I have not been able to find anything that will work...
I've also tried these two lines in the submit_form function, but got the same error

```
return redirect(view2, pn='hi')
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view2', args=('hi', )))
```

Comment: One doesn't redirect with data. A redirect is simply sending a response to the client that their requested resource has changed location so the client will then make a new request to the new location. Each request should be independent and any data needed should be found from the request itself (and potentially from various places like the database, etc.).

Comment: So, maybe you can point me in the right direction on what my ultimate goal is here... My django app takes in a .csv document and parses through it. Depending on the content, a new instance of a model may need to be created. If this is the case, I want to redirect to another page that has a form with the data from the upload pre-filled, and the rest blank and able to be filled out by the user. So, 'view2' is really a model form that I was trying to pass some existing information into via arguments. Is there a way to do this in Django?